# How to speed up or optimise [optimize] a hyperlink in HTML

Tags: html, hyperlink

Is there a way to speed up the time it takes to open a new browser page when clicking on a hyperlink?  The hyperlink goes to a specific index of a new page, but there is a delay from the time it takes to load the new web page and the time it takes to navigate to the index.

Here's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/KerryRuddock/snzp4kph/) to demonstrate the problem.

```
<div>
  JavaScript’s core—most often used and most fundamental—data type is the Object data type. JavaScript has one complex data type, the <a rel="bookmark" href="https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.6" target="_blank">Object data type</a>,
  and it has five simple data types: Number, String, Boolean, Undefined, and Null. Note that these simple (primitive) data types are immutable (cannot be changed), while objects are mutable (can be changed).</div>
```

Comment: There is a pause to navigate to section 8.6 The Object Type.  Anyway to speed that up?

Comment: Not without control over the ecma-international.org site...

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to speed up the time it takes to open a new browser page when clicking on a hyperlink?

No, this is entirely dependent on the network connection and the server that's serving the document to the browser. Documents that are large enough with the fragment being far enough into the document will inevitably leave the user waiting at the top of the page for as long as the fragment isn't yet loaded.

Comment: What you say makes sense.  I knew I had a bookmark somewhere prior to asking this question on prebrowsing and this topic is a little over my head. https://css-tricks.com/prefetching-preloading-prebrowsing/ would any of these techniques help out with speeding up the hyperlink?